# Python requests login mcdonalds

Tags: python, python-requests

My problem is that when logging into mcdonalds login page, i recieve a 200 code which is ok, but when i print the text from the html page it says "content modified" which i dont know why. I'm not sure what headers i should be using (there is no CSRF token) my data for login contains my account info, so i won't post that.

i also tried using a session.

```
headers = {'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Set-Cookie': 'HttpOnly;Secure, MCDCountry_code=US; path=/', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36', 'referer': 'https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/subscription.html', 'origin': 'https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/'}
data= {
    "signinemail" : "myemail",
    "signinpassword": 'mypass'
    }
e = requests.post("https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/subscription.html", data=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
```

i expected to be redirected to home page, but nothing. My question is what am  i doing wrong?

Comment: In many cases, the issue is that you're posting the request without an appropriate cookie, that would have been set on the browser when loading the login form.

Comment: @Grismar okay, i dont know how to get the cookie and use it in a header. any suggestions?

Comment: Use a session, and do both the GET and POST from the session.  This allows the server to set whatever cookies it wants.

Comment: @JohnGordon apparently the claim is that "`noahbn` also tried using a session".

@noahbn could you show the code you used w/a session?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is likely to be a missing cookie on the `POST` request.

Use your favourite browser to look at the request as it is being sent when logging in through the browser. Try to figure out what the cookie contains.

In Python you can then pass along a similar cookie:

```
import requests

jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
jar.set('some_var', 'some_value', domain='www.mcdonalds.com', path='/us/en-us')

headers = {'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Set-Cookie': 'HttpOnly;Secure, MCDCountry_code=US; path=/', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36', 'referer': 'https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/subscription.html', 'origin': 'https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/'}
data= {
    "signinemail" : "myemail",
    "signinpassword": 'mypass'
    }
e = requests.post("https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/subscription.html", cookies=jar, data=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
```

Note that I haven't tested this, I don't want to log on to the McDonalds site, but this is the pattern. Note that you don't have to use a `jar` if you only want to pass a single cookie and just want it to apply to the request directly. The `jar` is there to allow you to define multiple cookies, or point them at specific parts of the site for the request. Simple cookie:

```
my_cookie = {'some_var': 'some_value'}
e = requests.post("https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/subscription.html", cookies=my_cookie, data=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
```

As @John Gordon suggests, you can also perform a `GET` on the login page first and then obtain the needed cookies from there, passing them back along with the login `POST` request.